# EF4; Add foreign keys to model

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I've got quite a large Entity Framework 4 model (model first), which at the moment has all the relationships defined as associations, without Foreign Key properties.

Anyone know a way to add FK properties to the whole diagram other than by recreating the diagram from scratch or adding each one manually?

I suppose one way would be to generate the database, then build a new model from the database, and then just go through cleaning up, unless there's any better suggestions?

I'm thinking another way would be to write something to tweak the XML.

Comment: Update - have begrudgingly done this manually. Leaving question open in case anyone knows of a better way as I'm sure it won't be the last time anyone wants to retrospectively add FKs.

Comment: I had this happen to me as well.  I got kind of frustrated with it and gave up on the Model-First approach and created a Database Project in my solution.  Turns out that having the database schema in the solution like that makes it easy to migrate the database if you evolve the schema over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although writing some code to manipulate the XML would achieve what you need, unless this is something you intend to use again in the future (unlikely), I think you're better off doing this manually in the designer.  Having said that if you have the time to do it you'll find it an excellent way to learn the inner workings of Entity Frameworks DSL.  Something that in my experience is useful when you come to make changes to the model once the schema has gone live.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the steps I took:

1. Add a scalar property of proper type the dependent entity ("CategoryID" in "Product" for example)
2. Map that property to the proper column in the database using the Mapping window in the designer
3. Edit the association, you will need to add a referential constraint to the association. You can do that via the properties window. The principal will be the entity you are referencing (ie "Category") and the dependent will be the other (ie "Product")
4. This is all that is needed. When you "validate" that file, you will get an error in EF complaining about the existing Association Set Mapping. This is because there are two strategies now for that mapping. You will need to delete this one. The only way I found I could do that was to open the xml file. VS will highlight that area with squigglies. Just delete that node and you are good to go.